# Android: Accessing WCF on Local Host through android emulator using ksoap2

Tags: android, wcf, localhost, ksoap2

Okay I am really stuck in here ! I have tried it through many ways but invain. I am trying to access wcf web service(Local) through android application launched on emulator but my App crashes, here are the codes.

This is My Android

```
      public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

        /* I am not sure about these !! SOry */ 
 private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://localhost:1034/ILocation_Based_Reminder_WCF/getReminder";
 private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getReminder";
 private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://localhost:1034/";
 private static final String URL = "http://localhost:1034/Location_Based_Reminder_WCF.svc/";




@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


private void initialize()
{
    try {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

           // request.addProperty("3235466455");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try{
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("this is the message");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("this is stack tracer");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

            String resultData = result.toString();

            System.out.println(resultData);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
}
```

Thats the web service

interface

```
namespace Location_Based_Reminder
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "ILocation_Based_Reminder_WCF" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILocation_Based_Reminder_WCF
    {
        [OperationContract]
        String insertUser(long user);
        [OperationContract]
        String insertReminder(long user,String Location,String Time,String Time_Offset,String Date,String Date_Offset,int Status,String Description);
        [OperationContract]
        String getReminder(long userMSISDN);

    }
}
```

.svc file

```
namespace Location_Based_Reminder
{
     public class Location_Based_Reminder_WCF : ILocation_Based_Reminder_WCF
    {
        private BUS _bus;
        private ValueObject _vo;
        private void _initiate()
        {
            _bus = new BUS();
            _vo = new ValueObject();
        }





        #region getReminder
        public String getReminder(long userMSISDN)
        {
            _initiate();
            DataTable _table = new DataTable();
            _table = _bus.getReminder(3235466455);
            String check=null;
            foreach (DataRow row in _table.Rows)
            {
                check = row["reminder_Location"].ToString();
            }
            return check;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

and here is the message that i get

```
03-29 20:02:42.245: I/System.out(2102): this is the message
03-29 20:02:42.245: D/AndroidRuntime(2102): Shutting down VM
03-29 20:02:42.245: W/dalvikvm(2102): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.locationbasedreminderversionOne.Two/com.example.locationbasedreminderversionOne.Two.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at com.example.locationbasedreminderversionOne.Two.MainActivity.initialize(MainActivity.java:116)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at com.example.locationbasedreminderversionOne.Two.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-29 20:02:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2102):     ... 11 more
```

I have added permisions and stuff in android manifest. Please Help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you need to get the SOAP from the service that you have designed. Sample code as follows.

```
       String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/WriteToDB";
       String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
       String METHOD_NAME = "WriteToDB";
       String URL = "http://10.224.185.37/AndroidService.asmx?op=WriteToDB";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out the problem, whenever there is network communication involved in android it should not be done directly in onCreate method, for this Async Activities should be used.

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" on anddoir code refer to the android's localhost. 10.0.2.2 is the virtual IP of the computer's localhost ;-)